# Python-Ldap lib. Import LDIF

Tags: python, openldap, python-ldap, ldif

Is it possible to import LDIF like that

```
dn: cn=vpupkin,cn=people,ou=company,dc=domain,dc=com
c: UA
cn: vpupkin
employeetype: Indoor Front-end developer
gidnumber: 500
givenname: Vasya
homedirectory: /home/vpupkin
host: example.com
l: Kyiv
loginshell: /bin/bash
mail: vpupkin@domain.com
o: Microsoft
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: top
objectclass: shadowAccount
objectclass: ldapPublicKey
objectclass: extensibleObject
labeleduri: skype://test
sn: Pupkin
sshpublickey: ssh-rsa key
st: Trudova, 15
telephonenumber: 7777777777
uid: vpupkin
uidnumber: 1000
userpassword: {SHA}fEqNCco3Yq9h5ZUglD3CZJT4lBs=
```

using python-ldap library (http://www.python-ldap.org/)?

Yes, I can add new record to LDAP in such way http://www.grotan.com/ldap/python-ldap-samples.html#add but I am not sure about such text ldif-file.

PS. Full answer is here http://pastebin.com/eQU7xBfj

Comment: Why use Python at all? You can use this file directly with the `ldapadd` utility. No need to interpose further software, and certainly no need to wrtie any code.

Comment: @EJP because better to use python code in python script instead external linux command.

Comment: No it isn't. It is always and everywhere better to use existing and well-tested software, rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*python-ldap* contains an [LDIF Parser module](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldif.html). Use that to parse the LDIF and submit the resulting dictionary to `ldap_connection.add_s()`.

Example usage:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import ldif
from ldap import modlist

ldif_file = StringIO("""dn: cn=vpupkin,cn=people,ou=company,dc=domain,dc=com
c: UA
cn: vpupkin
""")

parser = ldif.LDIFRecordList(ldif_file)
parser.parse()

for dn, entry in parser.all_records:
    add_modlist = modlist.addModlist(entry)
    ldap_conn.add_s(dn, add_modlist)
```

Comment: could you help with any trivial example?

Comment: sorry, it's been a while since i needed this myself. I've added a small example

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below method too:

```
class MyLDIF(ldif.LDIFParser):
   def __init__(self, input):
      ldif.LDIFParser.__init__(self,input)

   def handle(self,dn,entry):
      ldif = modlist.addModlist(entry)
      l = ldap.open('localhost', 389)
      try:
          l.bind("cn=Manager,dc=exapmle,dc=org", "Secret123")
      except ldap.SERVER_DOWN, e:
          print "ldap server is down"
      else:
          l.add_s(dn, ldif)

 def enable_schema():
    parser = MyLDIF(open('/tmp/a1.ldif', 'rb'))
    parser.parse()
```

I have derived to the above solution using example given in [python-ldap docs](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldif.html#example)